# while loop with the if statement in python

Tags: loops

```
print ("Selection of the mode\n Easy \n Moderate \n tough")
selection = int(input("Please enter the right Choice!! > "))

while selection != '':
    if selection == 1:
        print("\ngoodluck")
    elif selection == 2:
        print('\nyou are brave')
    elif selection == 3:
        print ('\nyou must be kidding')
    selection = int(input("Please enter the right Choice!!! > "))
```

I am making a small program, new to python so have a bit of understanding problem, need to know my error when the user have typed in the correct selection like 1 or 2 or three it should go in a loop and run the if statement. Once that is done it should exit. But apparently that is not working perfectly.

```
print ("Selection of the mode\n Easy \n Moderate \n tough")
selection = input("Please enter the right Choice!! > ")

while selection != '':
    if selection == '1':
        print("\ngoodluck")
        break
    elif selection == '2':
        print('\nyou are brave')
        break
    elif selection == '3':
        print ('\nyou must be kidding')
        break
    selection = input("Please enter the right Choice!!! > ")
```

I am doing this now but goes through all the if statement but I just want to exit once the first selection is correct of the if statement.

Comment: you need to add `break` after all the print functions.

Comment: @AvinashRaj did that not working :/

Comment: `break` statement should work as avinashRaj said.

Comment: @Kutttayqarateraa Are you saying, if enter 1, it is not exiting?

Comment: okay @itzmeontv, The below answer is right but still the while loop is not exiting when when 1 or 2 or 3 is typed it is still recurring.

Comment: Did corresponding `print` working?

Comment: @itzmeontv working now, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print ("Selection of the mode\n Easy \n Moderate \n tough")
selection = int(input("Please enter the right Choice!! > "))

while selection != '':
    if selection == 1:
        print("\ngoodluck")
        break
    elif selection == 2:
        print('\nyou are brave')
        break
    elif selection == 3:
        print ('\nyou must be kidding')
        break
    selection = input("Please enter the right Choice!!! > ")
```

Also there is no need of `input()` multiple times.

```
print ("Selection of the mode\n Easy \n Moderate \n tough")
while True:
    selection = int(input("Please enter the right Choice!!! > "))
    if selection == 1:
        print("\ngoodluck")
        break
    elif selection == 2:
        print('\nyou are brave')
        break
    elif selection == 3:
        print ('\nyou must be kidding')
        break
```